# How to prettify an Object into JSON format using Javascript function(with out using JSON.strigify() method)

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to see is there any way to convert a string or an object into prettify JSON with out using JSON.stringify().

I want to convert {"key1":"val1","key2":["item1",{"item2key":1.2}]} into

```
{
  "key1": "val1",
  "key2": [
    "item1",
    {
      "item2key": 1.2
    }
  ]
}
```

using javascript with 2 spaces indentation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain your issues with `JSON.stringify()`, seeing as there are 2 posts regarding it?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I have no issues with JSON.stringify(), I just want to understand what is happening in the background.

Comment: Then it's best to take a look at [the standard](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-json.stringify).

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify()` can receive many args (cf. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

In your case: `JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know what happens in the background of the `JSON.stringify` just look at the source:

https://docs.sencha.com/touch/1.1.0/source/JSON.html

```js
JSON.stringify = function (value, replacer, space) {

// The stringify method takes a value and an optional replacer, and an optional
// space parameter, and returns a JSON text. The replacer can be a function
// that can replace values, or an array of strings that will select the keys.
// A default replacer method can be provided. Use of the space parameter can
// produce text that is more easily readable.

            var i;
            gap = '';
            indent = '';

// If the space parameter is a number, make an indent string containing that
// many spaces.

            if (typeof space === 'number') {
                for (i = 0; i < space; i += 1) {
                    indent += ' ';
                }

// If the space parameter is a string, it will be used as the indent string.

            } else if (typeof space === 'string') {
                indent = space;
            }

// If there is a replacer, it must be a function or an array.
// Otherwise, throw an error.

            rep = replacer;
            if (replacer && typeof replacer !== 'function' &&
                    (typeof replacer !== 'object' ||
                     typeof replacer.length !== 'number')) {
                throw new Error('JSON.stringify');
            }

// Make a fake root object containing our value under the key of ''.
// Return the result of stringifying the value.

            return str('', {'': value});
        };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that will help you:

**Beautinator**

*A quick and dirty javascript pretty printer for javascript objects that runs in the browser. Works for objects that contain functions.*

https://github.com/fresheneesz/beautinator

Example:

```
var result = beautinator({ "font-size": "26px","font-family": "'Open Sans', sans-serif",color: "white", overflow: "hidden",padding: "4px 4px 4px 8px",Text: { display: "block", width: "100%","text-align": "center", "padding-left": "2px","word-break": "break-word"}})
console.log(result)
```

Result:

```
{ "font-size": "26px",
  "font-family": "'Open Sans', sans-serif",
  color: "white", overflow: "hidden",
  padding: "4px 4px 4px 8px",
  Text: { display: "block", width: "100%",
          "text-align": "center", "padding-left": "2px",
          "word-break": "break-word"
  }
}
```